# Programmatically set DateTimePicker Tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, datetimepicker

I am trying to do the following, but it doesn't work:

```
MyDateTimePicker.ToolTipText = "test"; //Doesn't work
```

To be clear, I know how to add a tooltip to some control using the designer and how to change it's tooltip text programmatically but it doesn't seems to work for the DateTimePicker control. I don't understand since in the properties of the control in the designer I can see (and set) the ToolTip text.

This seems like a basic problem, but I can't find any information related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
var yourToolTip = new ToolTip();
//The below are optional, of course,

yourToolTip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
yourToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
yourToolTip.ShowAlways = true;

yourToolTip.SetToolTip(dateTimePicker1, "Oooh, you put your mouse over me.");
```

Comment: ok,  "yourToolTip.SetToolTip(dateTimePicker1, "string test");" did the trick! I see lof of similar answers. I don't know who answered first so I am marking the most voted as the correct one. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ToolTip` property for the `DateTimePicker`.

You have to do the following:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 3000;
toolTip.ShowAlways = true;
toolTip.SetToolTip(dateTimePicker1, "Tool Tip for DateTimePicker");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have a `Tooltip` property (or a `ToolTipText` property as changed in your edit).

You should try creating a new instance of the [`ToolTip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use it to set the tool tip for your `DateTimePicker` control:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

var toolTip = new ToolTip();

toolTip.SetToolTip(this.MyDateTimePicker, "String you want to be displayed here.");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property associated with a tool tip for a DateTimePicker that is why it doesn't work.